# MySql Workbench Error when connecting to MariaDb. Table 'performance_schema.user_variables_by_thread' doesn't exist

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I installed MariaDB 10.3.15 on Ubuntu 18.02 Linux. And trying to connect it from macOS Mojave using Mysql Workbench 8.0.6. I get the error as shown below

**15:41:34  Error loading schema content    Error Code: 1146 Table 'performance_schema.user_variables_by_thread' doesn't exist**

[image: Mysql Workbench Error]

On the left side, I see an error message "Tables could not be fetched". I am able to SSH into the server and use the database. I performed a clean install, but nothing worked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting aside the fact that MySQL Workbench is made for MySQL (as the name says), this problem was introduced in 8.0.16 and will be corrected in 8.0.17. The mentioned table doesn't exist in other versions than MySQL 8.

Comment: Thanks for clarification Mike. I was trying to fix MariaDB since yesterday. Switching to 8.015 version fixed the issue

Comment: +1 I've had the same error. The table also doesn't exist in older versions of MySQL. Statement from Oracle that the next WB version will fix this: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,674633,675074#msg-675074